# How to pass parameters in compiled code object?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, compilation, runtime

I want to pass few parameters in the python code object. I have tried the below code and it is running fine but I want to know how I can pass the value of `a` & `b` externally and assign return variable into another variable `c`.

```
codeInString = 'a = 5\nb=6\nsum=a+b\nprint("sum =",sum)\v return sum'
codeObject = compile(codeInString, 'sumstring', 'exec')

exec(codeObject)
```

Something like this:

```
codeInString = 'sum=a+b\nprint("sum =",sum) return sum'
codeObject = compile(codeInString, 'sumstring', 'exec')

c = exec(codeObject(a,b))
```

**Please note**: I am running this code in a distributed environment.

Comment: You mean like `exec(codeObejct, dict(a=5, b=6))`? Not sure what you mean about globally.

Comment: yes I want something like this .. exec(codeObejct, dict(a=5, b=6)).. but this is not working .. can you give me how CodeString will be corresponding to this.@don'ttalkjustcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you think you're defining a function in the `codeInString`, but you are not. Fixing that by removing the `return` statement, the following works:

```
from textwrap import dedent

codeInString = dedent("""\
    sum = a + b
    print("sum =", sum)
""")
codeObject = compile(codeInString, 'sumstring', 'exec')

exec(codeObject, dict(a=5, b=6))  # -> sum = 11
```

Also note the the return value of `exec()` is `None`.

Comment: thanks for help.. Yes I had tried this and it is working fine. But I am also stuck at another use case related to same problem. I have posted another question for that .. can you please help on it .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69151112/import-lib-not-working-with-exec-function

Comment: Nikk: Will take a look.