# Import Lib not working with exec function?

Tags: python, compilation, exec, lib

I have written the below code string and trying to execute it through the `exec` method. This code is running fine when I run it with global mode only.

```
codeRule = """import math
def fun (n):
    data = n
    data = data * math.pi
    print(data)
    return data
dd = fun(n)"""
    
codeObejct = compile(codeRule, 'sumstring', 'exec')
exec(codeObejct, dict(n = 10))
```

But my use case needs `dd` value outside of `exec` so I have used the below parameter to get `dd` value inside another dataframe.

```
loc = {}
exec(codeObejct, dict(n = 10), loc)
dd = loc["dd"]
```

But as soon as I use local it starts giving me an error regarding Lib Import such as

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sumstring", line 7, in <module>
  File "sumstring", line 4, in fun
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Can someone please help to solve this problem?

I have checked the below question's answer but I don't know how to fit it in my use case.

[Why doesn't an import in an exec in a function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505047/why-doesnt-an-import-in-an-exec-in-a-function-work)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (MRE) so folks without all those unrelated-to-the-problem-at-hand modules can work on your question.

Comment: Sure martineau,, let me update it.

Comment: @martineau, Done. Please look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got solution,

I was missing one point with `exec`. Below is the solution that I got and I hope it will work for my actual Use case

```
codeRule = """import math
def fun (n):
    data = n
    data = data * math.pi
    return data
"""
#export Function 
exec (codeRule, globals())

dd = fun(10)
dd
31.41592653589793
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69151372/355230) looks good. Here's another more-convoluted approach if you need a fallback for your use case:

```
codeRule = """\
import math

def fun(n):
    data = n
    data = data * math.pi
    return data

loc['dd'] = fun(n)
"""

codeObject = compile(codeRule, 'sumstring', 'exec')
loc = {}
exec(codeObject, dict(n=10, loc=loc))
print(f"{loc['dd']=}")  # -> loc['dd']=31.41592653589793
```

Comment: @Nikk: I'm curious, didn't your own answer work?

Comment: my answer working fine.. and I have deployed it on Prod as well. Since your answer also looks correct so I have marked your answer correct answer since I can't tick my own answer :) Stackoverflow things..

Comment: Well, thank you very much for the gesture—however I believe you *can* accept your own answer. maybe after waiting a certain amount of time. IMO yours is the better of the two (I upvoted it).